# Ubuntu 16.04 MSI Steelseries keyboard doesnt work properly

Tags: drivers, 16.04, keyboard, touchpad, msi

I have MSI GE62 6QC laptop with internal Steelseries keyboard with installed Ubuntu 16.04.

I've got weird problems with keyboard. When I try to type in apps like gedit or firefox it doesn't work. But when I open second instance of app, keyboard works, but only in second app instance.

Keyboard works ok only with Ubuntu "things" like searching etc.

Also touchpad is not working, so it would be great if someone would have solution to this problem also ;)

Thanks!

## Update

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
```

Partially helps, but console still does not work properly. I need to open next console. So this might be some clue.

Comment: Have you installed Nvidia proprietary drivers? (yes, graphics drivers are often related with such issues and you need them anyway for better performance, it's a gaming laptop after all).

Comment: Nope, I'll try this.

Comment: Nope, I didn't work.

Comment: By "second instance" do you mean you close it and then open it again? Or you open a second window?

Comment: I meant second window ;)

Comment: @hya, could you [edit] the question and add output of `env | grep -i -e im -e lang`

Comment: @user.dz thanks! I've changed remaining ibuses to xim and now all works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List IM modules:

```
env | grep -i -e im -e lang
```

Set all ibus to xim. For example:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
```

Comment: I've done this @hya , but I'm not sure I did it right. I added the exports to my ~/.profile file, and I've restarted my PC. Is that all? I don't have the same issue than you, but I had 2 lines set to ibus instead of xim. My problem is with the less / great than characters. They aren't being printed, instead they show ç / Ç characters.